# Is there a difference in all of those SFP+/SFP+ Driect Attach cables?

Tags: networking

I have a HP E6600-24G-4XG switch with 4 SFP+ ports and I want to connect 4 servers to it. All 4 servers have a HP nc522sfp 10G nic.

Now I was looking for cheaper SFP+ cables, for connecting these servers to the switch and I noticed that there is a huge price difference.

The HP cables are like 6 times more expensive compared to the huawai SFP+ direct attach cables.

I was going to buy Huawei SFP-10G-CU1M cables for them. (According to my supplier the ean code is HUW-02310MUN)

These cables are 6 times cheaper, compared to the HP cables.

Will it work with these cables?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, they are all the same. They follow the same industry standards, namely SFF-8679. The only difference is that the transceivers have an identity register, which tells the NIC who is connecting. Certain vendors lock down their cards only to work with certain wires. You can look into reprogramming the EEPROM on your NIC to get around this issue.

Comment: Vendors typically have unpublished commands to allow 3rd party SFPs.  There is truth to their claim that only their own SFPs are tested.  Bootleg SFPs do exist and do cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

HP normally checks if the SFP/SFP+ transceivers are from a known vendor (i.e. HP). So not all 3rd-party modules will work.

I regularly use http://www.flexoptix.net/en/ products, as they can be programmed to look like whatever vendor you need.

Comment: I think I better play save and get the HP J9281B instead. So we don't get unexpected problems

Answer (score 0):

They have difference but not a big issue.
HP DAC Cable programmed specific code in MCU so that using non-HP DAC cables could trigger the warning that is unsupported by HP.

But still there are many thrid vendors you can find, which claim the compatibility with HP.Not all third party's cable work fine on HP, though.
I recommend you a vendor, [10Gtek](https://www.sfpcables.com/sfp-passive-dac). They have special method to decode HP’s cable so it can work fine in HP’s device. Besides, their cables are very cost-effective.